# Calculate the probability that after 90 minutes exactly 7 patients will have entered the emergency department

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Patients enter emergency department following a Poisson process with intensity 6 patients per hour.

1. Calculate the probability that during 90 minute interval there will have entered exactly 7 patients.
2. The last patient arrived at 13:00. What is the probability that the next patient will arrive before 13:15?

So, my solution:

1. $$\lambda = 1.5 * 6 = 9 \\ P(X = 7) = \frac{e^{-9} 9^7}{7!} \approx 0.117$$
2. $$\ \ \lambda = \frac{6}{60} \cdot 15 = \frac{3}{2} \\ P(X = 1) = \frac{e^{-3/2}\cdot \frac{3}{2}}{1!} \approx 0.552$$

I am not sure about the second one.

Comment: (1) In R, where `dpois` is a Poisson PDF, code `dpois(7,9)` returns
$0.1171161.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(2) The waiting time for the next event is $W \sim \mathsf{Exp}(\mathrm{rate\,}=\lambda = 6.)$
You seek $P(W \le 3/4) = 0.9889.$

One expects six events per
hour (one every 10 min.) on average, so it is very likely the next event occurs within
45 min.

In R, where `pexp` denotes an exponential CDF, and using R as a calculator:

```
pexp(3/4, 6)
[1] 0.988891
1 - exp(-6*(3/4))
[1] 0.988891
```

[image]

```
curve(dexp(x,6), 0, 1.5, lwd=2, ylab="PDF", xlab="w", 
      main="Density of EXP(6)") 
 abline(v=0, col="green2");  abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v = 3/4, col="red", lty="dotted", lwd=2)
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, I meant 15 minutes. So with dpois(1, 3/2) = 0.334, but calculating it the way I did it with the formula, gives me a result of 0.552. The 1-exp(-1/4*6) gives a result of 0.776. I understand that dpois and 1-exp are linked. But the previous commenter accepted my first answer as correct and the function dpois gives the result I computed. I don't understand why now I should use the 1-exp function. Why my own computed result is incorrect?

Comment: This is getting to be a mess: As I said in a previous comment, your answer to (1) is OK. For (2) if you've now decided you want $P(W < 1/4).$ then it's `pexp(1/4,6)`, which returns $0.7768698.$ Best to use $W$ for waiting times. But if you insist on using Poisson, then you need to use $Y\sim\mathsf{Pois}(3/2)$ and find $P(Y\ge1) = 1-P(Y=0),$ which computes in R as `1 - dpois(0, 3/2)` returning
$0.7768698.$ So the method and answer you show for (2) are wrong.

Comment: Ok, thank you. One more question. If you calculate the probability that during the 15 min. interval there will be another event by 1-dpois(0,3/2), does that imply that you calculate the probability that during these 15 min. there will occur 1 or more event?

Comment: The event that the next patient arrives before  13;15 obviously allows the _possibility_ that one or more will arrive before 13:15. // That's the reason I said it's best (= least confusing) to use exponential dist'n for waiting times. // If you want the probability that _exactly_ one patient arrives btw 13:00 and 13:15, then you need to say so. // This site works best with _exactly one_ clearly stated question at a time. So I'm signing off now, before we get chastised for 'chatting' in comments.

Comment: No, I wanted exactly what you answered for. Thanks.